# Scope of variables in KSH

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have written a sample KornShell function to split a String, put it in an array and then print out the values.
The code is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

splitString() {

    string="abc@hotmail.com;xyz@gmail.com;uvw@yahoo.com"

    oIFS="$IFS"; 
    IFS=';' 
    set -A str $string
    IFS="$oIFS"
}

splitString
echo "strings count = ${#str[@]}"
echo "first : ${str[0]}";
echo "second: ${str[1]}";
echo "third : ${str[2]}";
```

Now the `echo` does not print out the values of the array, so I assume it has something to do with the scope of the array defined.

I am new to Shell scripting, can anybody help me out with understanding the scope of variables in the example above?

Comment: Gotcha !!!! 
The script is now working , no issues with it. Had done a minor mistake of calling the function in a wrong fashion.
However would still like to understand the scope of variables in KSH

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default scope of a variable is the whole script.

However, when you declare a variable inside a function, the variable becomes local to the function that declares it. Ksh has [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scope), so the variable is also accessible in functions that are invoked by the function that declares the variable. This is tersely documented in the section on functions in the [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ksh/ksh.1.en.html#Functions.). Note that in AT&T ksh (as opposed to pdksh and derivatives, and the similar features of bash and zsh), this only applies to functions defined with the `function` keyword, not to functions defined with the traditional `f () { … }` syntax. In AT&T ksh93, all variables declared in functions defined with the traditional syntax are global.

The main way of declaring a variable is with the `typeset` [builtin](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ksh/ksh.1.en.html#Built-in_Commands.). It always makes a variable local (in AT&T ksh, only in functions declared with `function`). If you assign to a variable without having declared it with `typeset`, it's global.

The ksh documentation does not specify whether `set -A` makes a variable local or global, and different versions make it either. Under ksh 93u, pdksh or mksh, the variable is global and your script does print out the value. You appear to have ksh88 or an older version of ksh where the scope is local. I think that initializing `str` outside the function would create a global variable, but I'm not sure.

Note that you should use a local variable to override the value of `IFS`: saving to another variable is not only clumsy, it's also brittle because it doesn't restore `IFS` properly if it was unset. Furthermore, you should turn off globbing, because otherwise if the string contains shell globbing characters `?*\[` and one of the words happens to match one or more file on your system it will be expanded, e.g. `set -A $string` where `string` is `a;*` will result in `str` containing the list of file names in the current directory.

```
set -A str
function splitString {
  typeset IFS=';' globbing=1
  case $- in *f*) globbing=;; esac
  set -f
  set -A str $string
  if [ -n "$globbing" ]; then set +f; fi
}
splitString "$string"
```

Comment: You are using the POSIX function syntax.  In ksh93, if you use `function splitSpring { ... }` then scoping with `typeset` works fine, otherwise the typeset is ignored for scoping purposes.

Comment: @cdarke You're right, thanks. Do you happen to know the situation in ksh88? I can't reproduce the behavior the asker describes in ksh93.

Comment: In ksh88 (and bash) scoping works the same for both styles of function declarations.  In ksh93 the POSIX function syntax has POSIx functionality and nothing else, so function tracing is also affected.

Comment: @Gilles 
Thanks for the detailed explanation. It has helped a lot :)

Comment: ksh93 has lexical scoping only, not dynamic. Basically all other shells related to ksh use dynamic scope, including ksh88, bash, and zsh. In ksh93, manipulating non-local variables requires either using globals, or passing variables through namerefs. There are also static locals. You can also modify function behavior using the POSIX function definition syntax, or calling functions as arguments to the "dot" builtin.

Answer (score 3):

Variables are normally global to the shell they're defined in from the time they're defined.

The `typeset` command can make them local to the function they're defined in, or alternatively to make them automatically exported (even when they're updated.)

Read up "typeset" and "integer" in the manpage, or Korn's book.