# A shell script to run a process on linux

Tags: xml, linux, shell, command-line, process

Problem:
I am very new to shell scripting. I have two directories A and B, each containing a about 100 files. The files in folder A and B have the exact same names, but differ in content as they are xml responses from different servers.
I have a xmldiff utility that will find the differences in these files and generate another file result.xml for the differences and it works with following command:

```
 xmldiff A/file1.xml B/file1.xml Result/result1.xml
```

So, I need a shell script that will loop over folder A and B, pick filename1 from each folder,
pass it to xmldiff and get result.xml....(for all 100 files)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

APP="xmldiff"
A="folder path"
B="folder path"
result="folder path"


# This function extract the basename  /path/to/basename.ext -> basename
getBaseName(){
local name="$1"
basename=`echo "$name" | sed -r -e "s/.+\/([^\/]+)\.[^\.]+$/\1/"`
echo "$basename"
}

for _file in $A/*
do 
filename=`getBaseName "$_file"`
# I'm assuming here that you have only xml files ending in .xml
"$APP" "$A/${filename}.xml" "$B/${filename}.xml" "$result/${filename}_result.xml"

done
```

NOTE: Copy this in a new text file. Then from cmdline type : chmod +x yourfilename. To exec from same folder : ./yourfilename

Comment: You might consider putting double quotes around all your filenames and paths in case they contain spaces e.g. "$A/${filename}.xml"

Comment: You might find it easier to cd "$A" at the start and work from there instead of looping over $A/* from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, indeed. Careful with spaces in directory and file names. You avoid spaces if you can in *nix in general...

Comment: I am using ksh, and for some reason "local" keyword doesn't work. I get the following error:-ksh: local: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: remove "local" or replace by typeset. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000949/scope-of-variables-in-ksh

Comment: The above solution works. What if I have directories in A and B folders inside which I have the xml files. How do I iterate one more level down?

Comment: The script needs to be modified to handle folders, it was not mentioned in question. Recursivity is the way to go here..

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty solution, if the files in A and B has identical names

```
(cd A;find . -name \*xml -print0) | xargs -0 -n1 -I % echo xmldiff ./{A,B,Result}/"%"
```

try DRY-run 1st - remove the `echo` if satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file names are exactly same, simple solution could be,

```
A=absolute path for A
B=absolute path for B
Result=absolute path for Result

for filename in `ls A\`
do
  xmldiff A/${filename} B/${filename} Result/${filename}_Result.xml
done
```

This should work for given purpose.