# bash - two ways to write function syntax

Tags: linux, bash, function, sh, ksh

in bash we can write function , but actually we have two ways ( two syntax ) ,

Please advice

What the differences between  **example1** to **example2**

Or maybe there are no any differences?

```
 function I_love_function

 {

  .
  .

 }
```

---

```
I_love_function ()

{

  .
  .
}
```

How to call the function `I_love_function`

Comment: No difference. Use whatever you like.

Comment: No difference in bash - [except for a subtlety](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10927223/1275169). There *is* a [difference in ksh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553850/1275169).

Comment: `Function` should be `function`. Bash is case significant.

Comment: These are almost identical in bash, as @Blue Moon says. I think that to be POSIXly correct, you'd define your functions without the `function` keyword, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions

> Functions are declared using this syntax:

```
name () compound-command [ redirections ] 
or 
function name [()] compound-command [ redirections ]
```

> This defines a shell function named name. **The reserved word function is optional. If the function reserved word is supplied, the parentheses are optional**.

Answer (score 1):

`I_love_function () { }` is compatible with POSIX/original sh-based shells but if your script is only meant to run in Bash, then there won't be much difference and more of just a preference.

Personally I prefer `function func_name { }` format since `()` seems meaningless to me as it doesn't explicitly specify the accepted arguments to the function.