# how to escape paths to be executed with $( )?

Tags: bash, shell

I have program whose textual output I want to directly execute in a shell. How shall I format the output of this program such that the paths with spaces are accepted by the shell ?

```
$(echo ls /folderA/folder\ with\ spaces/)
```

Some more info: the program that generates the output is coded in Haskell ([source](https://gist.github.com/miguel-negrao/531dc5dca2525264dedd)). It's a simple program that keeps a list of my favorite commands. It prints the commands with 'cmdl -l'. I can then choose one command to execute with 'cmdl -g12' for command number 12. Thanks for pointing out that instead of $( ) use 'cmdl -g12 | bash', I wasn't aware of that...

Comment: Can you clarify by giving an example input and output?

Comment: Why do you have to execute them with `$()`?

Comment: I must be missing something here … why not just wrap the output in `"…"`? `"$(echo whatever)"`.

Comment: Ok, I think what I was missing was that I cannot quote the whole command, but I have to quote each argument of the command separately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by @mklement0, a safe algorithm is to wrap every argument in a pair of single quotes, and quote single quotes inside arguments as `'\''`. Here is a shell function that does it:

```
function quote {
    typeset cmd="" escaped
    for arg; do
        escaped=${arg//\'/\'\\\'\'}
        cmd="$cmd '$escaped'"
    done
    printf %s "$cmd"
}

$ quote foo "bar baz" "don't do it"
 'foo' 'bar baz' 'don'\''t do it'
```

Comment: Thanks - we're in the home stretch :) `ksh` curiously _requires_ that `quote() {` be replaced with `function quote {` (non-POSIX syntax), otherwise the `typeset` commands will create _global_ variables (at least in AT&T `ksh` versions - verified on `ksh 93u` on OS X 10.9.4) - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12004099/45375

Comment: @mklement0 I had forgotten that part, but I actually remembered it and fixed it several minutes *before* your last comment. If there were a reward for effort spent on low-profile SO answers, we'd be eligible by now.

Comment: :) I do feel proud - I'll link to this from my résumé. Kidding aside: I learned a thing or two, so I don't feel it was wasted effort. One last suggestion: how about highlighting the shiny three-shell compatibility in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

> How shall I format the output of this program such that the paths with
>   spaces are accepted by the shell ?

The shell cannot distinguish between spaces that are part of a path and spaces that are separator between arguments, unless those are properly quoted. Moreover, you actually need proper quoting using single quotes (`'`...`'`) in order to "shield" all those characters combinations that might otherwise have special meaning for the shell (`\`, `&`, `|`,  `||`,  ...).

Depending the language used for your external tool, their might be a library available for that purpose. As as example, Python has [pipes.quote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) ([shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) on Python 3) and Perl has `String::ShellQuote::shell_quote`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that languages may have such functions already. To add an exotic one: AppleScript has `quoted form of`.

Comment: I guess for haskell I can use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shell-escape-0.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand, but don't you just want to pipe through the shell?

For a program called `foo`

```
$ foo | sh
```

To format *output* from your program so Bash won't try to space-separate them into arguments either update, probably easiest just to double-quote them with any normal quoting method around each argument, e.g.

```
mkdir "/tmp/Joey \"The Lips\" Fagan"
```

As you saw, you can backslash the spaces alternatively, but I find that less readable ususally.

EDIT:
If you may have special shell characters (``` &|``()[]$ ``` etc), you'll have to do it the hard/proper way (with a specific escaper for your language and target - as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just spaces you need to worry about, but other characters such as `[` and `]` (glob a.k.a pathname-expansion characters) and metacharacters such as `;`, `&`, `(`, ...

You can use the following approach:

- Enclose the string in *single* quotes.
- Replace existing single quotes in the string with `'\''` (which effectively breaks the string into multiple parts with spliced in `\`-escaped single quotes; the shell then reassembles the parts into a single string).

Example:

`I'm good (& well[1];)` would encode to `'I'\''m good (& well[1]);'`

Note how single-quoting allows literal use of the glob characters and metacharacters.
Since single quotes themselves can never be used within single-quoted strings (there's not even an escape), the splicing-in approach described above is needed.